# Trigger not setting DATETIME correctly

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.7

I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE assignment (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  course_id INT NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(128),
  assigned DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  due DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

with the following trigger:

```sql
DELIMITER ;;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS assignment_due_date;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER assignment_due_date
    BEFORE INSERT ON `assignment`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF (NEW.due IS NULL) THEN
            SET NEW.due=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
        END IF;
    END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

The intent is to set a default due date of 1 week (7 days), unless the INSERT already specifies a due date. However, whenever I insert a row, the due date ends up the same as the assigned date, without any error messages. Why would the trigger not update the due column?

Note that this behaves as expected when the INSERT statement *does* specify a value for the due column, and only misbehaves when a value is not provided. `INSERT INTO assignment (course_id, title, due) VALUES (12, 'Hemingway Essay', '2019-06-12')` populates the assigned and due columns with the current time and `2019-06-12`, as expected, but `INSERT INTO assignment (course_id, title) VALUES (12, 'Hemingway Essay')` populates both columns with the current time.

---

**UPDATE**

I've removed the DEFAULT value of the `due` column, so the table now looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE assignment (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  course_id INT NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(128),
  assigned DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  due DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

With no trigger in place, the following INSERT fails (due to the lack of default value):

```
 INSERT INTO assignment (course_id, title) VALUES (12, 'Hemingway Essay')
```

which is expected. With the following three variations of the trigger in place, I would expect the due date to be set to one week out, but it always ends up with the current time:

```sql
IF (NEW.due IS NULL) THEN
    SET NEW.due=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
END IF;
```

```sql
SET NEW.due=COALESCE(NEW.due, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

```sql
SET NEW.due=(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 7 DAY); -- forget conditions, just always set
```

Comment: *However, whenever I insert a row, the due date ends up the same as the assigned date, without any error messages.* Very strange... see [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4W63fzd2wxY9fWrBKKs2LV/1) (trigger text was simplified).

Comment: @Akina I've created a [fork of that fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56n6Pbq3WLB28SWXUr1R6V/0) with a new insert statement that reproduces the issue. It seems if the column is explicitly inserted as NULL, it works as expected, but if it is omitted, the trigger doesn't work.

Comment: If some field is NOT listed in the fields list, then DEFAULT is applied before any trigger firing.

Comment: So the best solution is likely to remove the DEFAULT value of the column

Comment: *remove the DEFAULT value of the column* That's right.

Comment: @Akina Removing the DEFAULT value doesn't seem to fix it (although the fiddle appears to work correctly). If I remove the trigger as well, the INSERT gets rejected due to lack of default value, but with the trigger it always sets due date to current time (even without the IF or COALESCE, just "always set due date to 1 week")

Comment: *Removing the DEFAULT value doesn't seem to fix it* ?? see [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56n6Pbq3WLB28SWXUr1R6V/1) - while removing DEFAULT value `due` for 'title 3' is correctly set by trigger. What's wrong? The whole logic: copy current record to OLD structure, create NEW record structure (with all fields), set its fields values according to the query (if the field is omitted, then set it to default, and if default absent, then set it to null - so `due` is set to null), then fire before trigger (which set `due` to today+1week), then update, then fire after trigger, then done.

Comment: @Akina sorry, got interrupted while writing a clarifying update. Verified that the no default value scenario is working correctly (removed trigger, INSERT fails without value), and tested several variations of the trigger, all of which set the date incorrectly (despite working just fine in the fiddle)

Comment: Why not set the default to be 7 days from the current date instead of having to fire a trigger to check if it is null?

Comment: @JoeW That was my initial approach, but functions are not allowed as default values in MySQL 5.

Comment: That is good to know

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for `NULL`, yet you are not letting it be `NULL` -- either by having a `DEFAULT` or `NOT NULL`.

So change to

```
due DATETIME NULL,
```

And, for less confusion between "timestamps" and "datetimes", use

```
SET NEW.due = COALESCE(NEW.due, NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Comment: The `IF` and `COALESCE` approach check for null, but my 3rd variation on the trigger (always set to +7 days) exhibits the same behavior (setting it to current time).

Comment: @yoozer8 - are you implying the `+ INTERVAL 7 DAY` is being ignored?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the case.